# Rename JOINT_NAMES in ur_driver test_move.py

Tags: ros, roslaunch, universal-robot, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I `rosrun ur_driver test_move.py` and would like to change the names of the joints which used. Originally they are initialized in the test_move.py, sadly I can't just edit this file, so I would like to find out if I can do this maybe with a launch file.

In test_move.py the joint names are saved in a character array like this:

```
JOINT_NAMES = ['shoulder_pan_joint','shoulder_lift_joint',...]
```

The overall question:
Can I effect the names of the joints via a launchfile. If yes how and if not, are there other ways to effect it.

My thoughts are about a Launch-File like this:

```
<node pkg="ur_driver" type="test_move.py" name="follow_joint_trajectory">
<param name="JOINT_NAMES" value="['J0','J1',...]"/>
</node>
```

EDIT 1: During writing I may already obtained my answer. I need to check at home. If you probably know something important to know about please feel free as to answer me.
I am not sure about how to write `value="['J0','J1',...]"` in an exact way. I still get an error.

EDIT 2: So far I tried about and read the [information](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) about the `<param>` tag, but as I understand it is not changing the variables used within the file. And there was also no reaction yet.
This is my launch file:

```
<arg name="robot_ip" />

<param name="/robot_ip_address" type="str" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>

<node pkg="industrial_robot_client" type="robot_state" name="robot_state"/>

<node pkg="industrial_robot_client" type="motion_streaming_interface" name="motion_streaming_interface"/>

<node pkg="industrial_robot_client" type="joint_trajectory_action" name="joint_trajectory_action"/>

<node pkg="ur_driver" type="test_move.py" name="follow_joint_trajectory">
    <param name="JOINT_NAMES" value="['J0','J1','J2','J3','J4','J5']"/>
    <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/cancel" to="/joint_trajectory_action/cancel"/>
    <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/feedback" to="/joint_trajectory_action/feedback"/>
    <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/goal" to="/joint_trajectory_action/goal"/>
    <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/result" to="/joint_trajectory_action/result"/>
    <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/status" to="/joint_trajectory_action/status"/>
</node></launch>
```

Is there a way to change this on the fly or do I need to build the test_move.py in a new package with the right names?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195376/rename-joint_names-in-ur_driver-test_move.py/) by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For solving my problem I split it up in two approaches:

1. Copy test_move.py into my own package and change the joint names, as well as the topic name it advertises.
2. Use features that are already implemted in ROS-I and do needed changes via launch file.

Informations that are important for both approaches:
Out of a `joint_names.yaml`, which I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/swri-ros-pkg-dev/9TGw26vLMYY/50DaJ4OHP-YJ), I got the names the Joints should have.

**The first approach**:
I copied the `test_move.py` in a package created by myself and got it to run with changing the `JOINT_NAMES` and the topic advertised. Here are the lines I modified:

```
JOINT_NAMES = ['joint_1', 'joint_2', 'joint_3', 'joint_4', 'joint_5', 'joint_6']
client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('joint_trajectory_action', FollowJointTrajectoryAction)
```

And I call it with these commands:

```
roscore
roslaunch industrial_robot_client robot_interface_streaming.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.101
rosrun rospy_pkg test_move
```

*This for the first works!* But results in an error message listed bellow in this question.

**The second approach**:
Later on I found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_robot_client/joint_naming), that the process of copying the `test_move.py` and modify it is not necessary. One can use the original `test_move.py` in `the ur_driver` package and set the rosparam `controller_joint_names`. It will have the same effect as writing an own modified `test_move.py`.

```
<launch>
   <arg name="robot_ip" />
   <param name="/robot_ip_address" type="str" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
   <rosparam param="controller_joint_names">['shoulder_pan_joint', 'shoulder_lift_joint', 'elbow_joint','wrist_1_joint', 'wrist_2_joint', 'wrist_3_joint']</rosparam>

   <node pkg="industrial_robot_client" type="robot_state" name="robot_state"/>
   <node pkg="industrial_robot_client" type="motion_streaming_interface" name="motion_streaming_interface"/>
   <node pkg="industrial_robot_client" type="joint_trajectory_action" name="joint_trajectory_action">
      <remap from="joint_trajectory_action/feedback" to "follow_joint_trajectory/feedback"/>
   </node>
   <node pkg="ur_driver" type="test_move.py" name="follow_joint_trajectory">
      <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/cancel" to="/joint_trajectory_action/cancel"/>
      <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/goal" to="/joint_trajectory_action/goal"/>
      <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/result" to="/joint_trajectory_action/result"/>
      <remap from="follow_joint_trajectory/status" to="/joint_trajectory_action/status"/>
   </node>
</launch>
```

*This also works!* But results in the same error message as approach nr. 1 mentioned above.
Here is the error message:

```
[joint_trajectory_action-X] process has died [pid 19413, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/industrial_robot_client/joint_trajectory_action
```

So far I found out it has to do with the remapping of the the `.../feedback topic`. Attention! In Version Nr. 2 I do a remapping in the launch file. In Version Nr. 1 it is done by ROS-I automatically.
Any ideas what and why it happens?

---

Originally posted by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) with karma: 27 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-21**:
Parts of the errormessage of both procedures that I forgot:

```
joint_trajectory_action: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback_<std::allocator<void> >]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:\

1. There is no `test_move.py` in `industrial_robot_client`, 2) "set a rosparam according to the launch file here below": that only works for the nodes in `industrial_robot_client`, not for your `test_move.py`. Really, just update the Python test script, don't make things harder than they need be.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:
You need to change the jointnames because by default (as you found), `industrial_robot_client` (IRC) uses `joint_1, joint_2, etc`. That needs to match the names in the goal that you send to the `joint_trajectory_action` node. Either update `test_move.py`, or use `controller_joint_names` for IRC.

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-22**:
I did how you said. I am updating my answer at the moment for better understandability.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:
Your approach is sane, you have just run into a bug, see [industrial_core/issues/85](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/issues/85). The ActionServer needs feedback from your robot to see whether a TrajPt has been reached. You're not sending any, and it causes the crash.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:
And again: you should've updated your original question with this new info.

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-22**:
This is really usual for me running into a bug, but thanks god you told me.
I need some time to read through this.
I wanted to give an answer this time and start a new question. But how it is in the life of a technician four hours are nothing compared to our projects and pass much too fast.

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-22**:
Ok it was not so much to read and not too complicated. It seems like there is no workaround at the moment without one of the ROS-I controllers with the specific drivers. I guess you also don't know if something will be done? How can I do something?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:
Implement the robot (joint) state side of your implementation first. You need this anyway, and as a bonus you can then use the info that sends to the IRC `robot_state` node to get things to work with `joint_trajectory_action`.

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-22**:
I am following the bug report of ROS-I. What does it mean to reject a goal?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:
It means the ActionServer will not execute the requested action. That is possibly the only logical action to take, seeing as without feedback the server cannot determine whether a goal has been reached (it cannot compare desired and actual states).

Perhaps it would be better to post on the issue.